# Switch between JPA and Mongo in Spring Boot MVC app

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have this web app written in Spring boot and it mainly uses JPA for database. I have a simple entity and then I have a repository that extends CrudRepository with some methods that fetch data from the database. Basically everything from this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

But now I need to have a second database and it must be MongoDB. Everything is identical to the JPA, but now I have a new repository class, that this time extends MongoRepository.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}

public interface CustomerRepositoryMongo extends MongoRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

So now I have two classes, CustomerRepository and CustomerRepositoryMongo. In my main I am filling the db like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            // save a couple of customers
            repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
            repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
        };
    }

}
```

How can I easily switch between the two dbs? I think I should maybe use profiles and select somewhere in application.properties which profile should be active, but I am new to this and I have no idea how to do it. I cannot have both interfaces with the same name and somehow I need to tell the commandLineRunner which repo should it use.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, you want to use profiles.

```
@Bean( name = "customerRepository" )
@Profile( "jpa")
CrudRepository getCustomerRepository()
{
    return _customerRepository;
}

@Bean( name = "customerRepository" )
@Profile( "mongo")
MongoRepository getCustomerRepositoryMongo()
{
    return _customerRepositoryMongo;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customerRepository")
CrudRepository _crudRepository;
```

In application.properties, you can now set **spring.profiles.active** to jpa or mongo to switch between databases.

Comment: Thanks. So am I supposed to create these getters as you wrote? If so, where? Or should I put the Bean and Profile annotation to the interfaces that I wrote about in my original question?

Comment: You can put the getters (with Bean and Profile annotations) on any class that is part of the Spring Boot component scan. In the code example above, you could put them in your Application class. Just to be clear, you need to autowire those private fields in the same class (e.g. @Autowired private CustomerRepositoryMongo _customerRepositoryMongo;)

Comment: Ok I understand, but simply those getters are giving me an error 'cannot resolve _customerRepository.'. It does not know them.

Comment: If it can't resolve "customerRepository", then that means you are not running with one of the associated profiles (e.g. "jpa" or "mongo") as your active profile.